# FromBody in Post method - Postman - null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

I want to pass a model as a body (row) in Postman.

```
[{
"MyArguments": [{
"arg1": "myString1",
"arg2": "myString2"
}]
}]
```

In my model on API side I have

```
public class MyArguments{
public string arg1 {get; set;}
public string arg2 {get; set;}
}
```

My route is

```
/myApi/myController/myControllerMethod
```

While debuging I can see there is MyArguments with null for both string values.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your API pls?

Comment: It's not an API thing because MyArguements is null at the very first API call. It's not even entering any code yet and MyArguments is already empty

Comment: Can you show your API pls? I need to know what  API input parameter like.

Answer (score 0):

I you use a Postman, try just

```
{
"arg1": "myString1",
"arg2": "myString2"
}
```

and maybe you need to add [FromBody] to your API method

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone with a similar problem - try older version of postman. I downloaded v 6 and it works perfectly fine. Check Postman's GitHub - a problem with POST body was reported few months ago